# How to control size of flextable objects with big chunks of text in rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, flextable

I was struggling while creating a table using flextable in RMarkdown, where for a large string of text within a table, the PDF (and HTML) output kept printing a very small table. Changing the settings in the chunk header (e.g. fig.height) or using flextable::autofit() or flextable::width() did not work. An example:

```
library(tidyverse) # for %>%
library(flextable)
```

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl. Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Odio euismod lacinia at quis. Pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor."
df = as.data.frame(text)

text_in_box = flextable(df) %>%
  theme_box() %>%
  delete_part(part = "header") %>%
  align(align = "left", part = "all") %>%
  set_caption("Interesting text") %>% 
  autofit()
  
knitr::knit_print(text_in_box)
```

[image: output for the example above]

Answer (score 2):

The answer I found is the flextable::height() function. This controls the height for a *row*, and not a *line*, as I wrongfully assumed. As all the text is put into one row, it shrinks the text to very small if the height() is on default. So you need to tinker a bit with the exact height that works for the amount of lines you have, in this case it was height = .6. I can imagine adding a few new lines (using "\n") to a body of text might also be useful if you want to manipulate the amount of text on one line, which would in turn affect the height you might want to set in height().

```
text_in_box = flextable(df) %>%
  theme_box() %>%
  delete_part(part = "header") %>%
  align(align = "left", part = "all") %>%
  set_caption("Interesting text") %>% 
  autofit() %>%
  height(height = .6)
  
knitr::knit_print(text_in_box)
```

[image]

Hope this answer saves someone the time it took me to figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using an old version of flextable. You were using the 3rd case, I think you would be interested by the 1st and 2nd case:

````
---
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(tidyverse) # for %>%
library(flextable)
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. Ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl. Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Odio euismod lacinia at quis. Pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis. Convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor."
df = as.data.frame(text)
```

## With `set_table_properties(layout = "autofit")`

```{r}
flextable(df) %>%
  theme_box() %>%
  delete_part(part = "header") %>%
  align(align = "left", part = "all") %>%
  set_caption("Interesting text") %>% 
  set_table_properties(layout = "autofit")
```

## With a fixed width

```{r}
flextable(df) %>%
  theme_box() %>%
  delete_part(part = "header") %>%
  align(align = "left", part = "all") %>%
  set_caption("Interesting text") %>% 
  width(width = 4) 
```

## With a fixed width and a fixed height

```{r}
flextable(df) %>%
  theme_box() %>%
  delete_part(part = "header") %>%
  align(align = "left", part = "all") %>%
  set_caption("Interesting text") %>% 
  width(width = 4) %>% 
  height(height = .6) %>% 
  hrule(rule = "exact", part = "all")
```
````

[image]

Comment: hey David, I should have mentioned that I am knitting a PDF (bookdown::pdf_document2), and none of those methods seem to work in that case.. See my output [here](https://imgur.com/a/tU0Q3IM)